# iterate neighbors along with attributes

Tags: python, networkx

In networkx

`gr.nodes(data=True)`

returns the list of nodes along with the attributes present on each node. Is it possible to get all the neighbors along with attributes of a given node in the graph.

Neighbors function doesn't accept any optional boolean parameter.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Use the [`adjacency_iter`](http://networkx.lanl.gov/reference/generated/networkx.Graph.adjacency_iter.html) if you want to iterate over them or [`adjacency_list`](http://networkx.lanl.gov/reference/generated/networkx.Graph.adjacency_list.html#networkx.Graph.adjacency_list) if you want them as a list.

**Edit**

I should add that neither of those will give you the attributes of node. But you can get them easily with `g.node[n]`.

Comment: i know that `g.node[n]` gives me a dict of the attributes of node `n`...i was wondering why neighbors function wouldn't take optional parameter.

Comment: @Graddy: That "Why" should be directed to the developers of `networkx`. Though I might have misunderstood your question. Do you want the attributes of *neighbors* or do you want the neighbors of a node and the node's attributes?

Comment: neighbors and their attributes

Comment: @Graddy: Unfortunately there is no built-in method for that. Your best bet is looping through them and getting data individually.

Comment: Some time has passed, is the status the same?

Comment: Both links are dead.